# Alterar coluna de CEP inserindo carácter hífen em Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, sql-update

Possuo uma tabela de cidades onde possuo os CEPs.

Os dados estão assim: 89620000
Gostaria de deixá-los assim: 89620-000

Como posso fazer isso em Firebird?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não deu muitos detalhes mas acho que isto irá resolver:

```
UPDATE cidades SET cep = SUBSTRING(cep FROM 1 FOR 5) || "-" || SUBSTRING(cep FROM 6 FOR 8);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/SubString.sql).

Se a coluna tinha o tamanho de 8 caracteres evidentemente você terá que aumentá-la antes.

Saiba que o mais comum é não armazenar penduricalhos nos dados. Em geral a aplicação ou mesmo *queries* específicas deveriam tratar o dado puro e colocar o hífen quando necessário. Claro que existem casos armazenar tudo pode ser necessário, pode ser o seu caso.

Comment: Bem isso que eu precisava. Muito obrigado

Comment: Ótimo exemplo, concordo plenamente com este trecho " Em geral a aplicação ou mesmo queries específicas deveriam tratar o dado puro e colocar o hífen quando necessário", +1